# Finding the syzygy (relation module) of a monomial ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

I have read pages 322-323 of "Commutative algebra, with a view toward algebraic geometry" by David Eisenbud, but it is still not much clear what are the steps of finding the syzygy.

I am practicing for myself finding the syzygy (relation module) of the following monomial ideal:

$$I_2 = (x_1^{34} x_2^{7}, x_1^{23}x_2^{19})$$ in $S = k[x_1, x_2].$

I understood that one of the steps is to find the $\sigma_{ij}$ but even this step is unclear to me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I am not wrong you have to check when af+bg=0, with I=(f,g). As they are both monomials, you can assume that a and b are monomials and that looks easier.

Comment: @196884e why I should do that?Also, I do not see exactly what will be $a,b, f ,g$ in my case, is $a=b=1$ in my case? ..... could you explain more please?

Comment: My definition of syzygy is that given a module M generated by (a1,..,an) the syzygy are the elements (b1,...,bn) such that a1b1+...+anbn=0. (I saw that there are more general definitions in terms of exact sequences and I dont know what happens there.) In this case you have I=(f,g)=(x^34y^7,x^23y^12), so if I am correct you have to compute the polynomials a and b such that af+bg=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ideal $I_2$ is generated by two monomials $u=x_1^{23}x_2^7 u_1, v=x_1^{23}x_2^7 v_1$ where $u_1=x_1^{11}, v_1=x_2^{12}$. Then, the resolution of $I_2$ is $$0\to S\to S^2\to I_2\to 0.$$ The right side map is just $u,v$. The left side map is $(v_1,-u_1)$.